# How to aggregate code coverage report in Hudson?

Tags: hudson, code-coverage, cobertura

I have project build with hudson CBS. and i am using cobertura for test coverage. Reports are generated and i am happy about it.

but i cannot find the delta of coverage %.

for e.g. 
check-in #1 - code coverage is 90% 
check-in #2 - code coverage is 75% i.e down by 15%.

can i achieve this in hudson cobertura plug-in? is there any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by parsing the cobertura XML files and pushing the individual build data into a database.  You can do this with other metrics, like number of tests and complexity.

Placing the results into a database gives you a wide range of display options.  We use Excel and SharePoint to display are most important metrics.  A simple web page with charts and graphs (is it still simple?) will also do the trick.

Comment: agree. i have done that in the past. i want to make sure that it is aligned with hudson reporting as its very intuitive

Comment: If staying in Hudson for display is that critical, you could take the approach above, but write to a properties files and use http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Plot+Plugin.